# Passbook app not updating in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

I've been following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22) tutorial on how to test passes on iOS6.0 passbook. I've followed the app's code line by line, but I'm having a problem. Whenever I click "add" on one of the passes, the PassView gets dismissed, but the pass does not show up in the simulator's PassBook application. I tried my own pass, as well as the ones that were given in the zip file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo pass. It did indeed work, so like you said there is probably a cert mixup. I'll look into it. Mind posting this as an answer so I can properly accept it? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. The certificate is not checked until after the Add button is pressed. This explains why it will preview in the view controller but fail to inject in Passbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a certificate problem - the certificates used to sign the demo pass may have expired, and your pass may have a signing error. Try [this pass](https://r.pass.is/92an80WoF99z.pkpass) and see if you still get a similar problem. If the problem is not with the pass bundle, can you post the console logs from the simulator or better still from a device after you press the Add button.